# In Alfresco, getting blank file when retrieving root version

Tags: version, alfresco

In Alfresco, I am trying to retrieve previous versions of files using this code:

```
        VersionHistory history = this.versionService
                .getVersionHistory(nodeRef);

        Version version = history.getVersion(previousDeployedVersion);
        NodeRef previousNode = version.getFrozenStateNodeRef();
```

It's working until I get to version 1.0, then I get blank content.
Is this normal behavior?
I also tried getRootVersion() but got the same results.

When I look at the file's details page, version history, I can "view" the contents of
the different versions. Version 1.0 show blank here also.

I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.
Thanks

This behavior was seen on files that were added to Alfresco through a virtual webdav drive. I found that when I added a file through
Alfresco Explorer using the "Add content" interface, everything works as I expected and version 1.0 can be read correctly.
Can anyone suggest what is causing this difference? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you check the CMIS code to get all the versions, then it's a bit different.
It also adds the current version to the list and does some checks.

```
 public List<NodeRef> getAllVersions(String objectId) throws CMISConstraintException, CMISVersioningException,
            CMISObjectNotFoundException, CMISInvalidArgumentException, CMISPermissionDeniedException
    {
        NodeRef nodeRef = getVersionSeries(objectId, NodeRef.class, true);

        List<NodeRef> objects = new LinkedList<NodeRef>();
        NodeRef pwc = checkOutCheckInService.getWorkingCopy(nodeRef);
        if (pwc != null)
        {
            objects.add(pwc);
        }
        VersionHistory versionHistory = versionService.getVersionHistory(nodeRef);
        if (versionHistory != null)
        {
            Version current = versionService.getCurrentVersion(nodeRef);
            while (current != null)
            {
                objects.add(current.getFrozenStateNodeRef());
                current = versionHistory.getPredecessor(current);
            }
        }
        else if (pwc == null)
        {
            objects.add(nodeRef);
        }
        return objects;
    }
```

Comment: This example is javascript. I need a java solution.

Comment: In the code above, where is the getVersionSeries method?

Comment: Download the SDK of Alfresco if you're developing and search through it. It's very easy to ask a question and not doing any research.